# Is pg_similarity still maintained?

Tags: postgresql, pg-search

I need to use similarity on my full text search on postgresql and I found [pg_similarity](https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity) and [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). According to the commits on the github the last commit on `pg_similarity` has 3 years. Is it maintained or should I use `pg_search` for my queries?

Comment: What about [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)?

Comment: @michel.milezzi thank you for your proposition but there is a caution `At present, the soundex, metaphone, dmetaphone, and dmetaphone_alt functions do not work well with multibyte encodings (such as UTF-8).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that a long time has passed since this question was asked, but the answer is yes, [pg_similarity](https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity)is still maintained. After the question was asked, multiple commits were made to that repo. This is a great repo.